# In every cell in a range press F2 and then enter

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic, send

I have a following code

```
Sub activate1()
Dim row As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Range, rr As Range

row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set rr = Range("A" & row & ":" & "AH" & row)

For Each r In rr
    r.Select
    Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    DoEvents
Next
End Sub
```

I want to dynamically search for the last row and than activate every single cell in the range by sending f2 and enter. However this codes send f2 to my VBA editor not to Excel spreadsheet. How to ensure that SendKeys is sending keys to a proper window?

In short i want to activate a range of cells..

Comment: what's your final end?

Comment: What do you mean precisely? Final end is that this marco sends f2 to an active window. I want to send those keys to a desired excel window

Comment: I mean, what do you make of sending `F2` and `Enter` to a selected cell? Do you want to update some formula result?

Comment: Yes. From a certain programm i have a range of inactivated cells which i want to activate.